SQL WHERE MAX date between current date and a date from a table
I'm on DB2 and I want to transform the statement above where numeric date (yyyymmdd) TXDTDBVL is compared with CURRENT DATE to have as condition the current month :
SELECT                                                                       
  '86',                                                                      
  B.GGCDOGA,                                                                 
  B.GGCDPAT1,                                                                
  CASE WHEN B.GGNOUGRAT <> ' ' THEN B.GGNOUGRAT ELSE B.GGNOUG END AS NOUG,   
  90,                                                                        
  SUM(A.TXMTLOYANX)                                                          
FROM                                                                         
  IKOS_F.UGCSALP A,                                                          
  IKOS_F.UGP B                                                               
WHERE                                                                        
  TXDTDBVL >= YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + 01 AND
  TXDTDBVL <= YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + 31    
  AND (                                                                      
    (B.GGCDOGA, B.GGNOUG) IN (                                               
      SELECT                                                                 
        DISTINCT IWCDORG,                                                      
        IWCDLOGT                                                               
      FROM                                                                     
        IKOS_F.IMWXRUP                                                         
    )                                                                          
    OR (B.GGCDOGA, B.GGNOUGRAT) IN (                                           
      SELECT                                                                   
        DISTINCT IWCDORG,                                                      
        IWCDLOGT                                                               
      FROM                                                                     
        IKOS_F.IMWXRUP                                                         
    )                                                                          
  )                                                                            
  AND A.TXCDOGA = B.GGCDOGA                                                    
  AND A.TXNOUG = B.GGNOUG                                                      
  AND A.TXCDTTARIF = B.GGCDTTARIF                                              
GROUP BY                                                                       
  B.GGCDOGA,                                                                   
  B.GGCDPAT1,            
CASE WHEN B.GGNOUGRAT <> ' ' THEN B.GGNOUGRAT ELSE B.GGNOUG END; 

into this where numeric date TXDTDBVL is compared with MAX(CURRENT DATE, numeric date B.GGDTMSUG) :
SELECT                                                                       
  '86',                                                                      
  B.GGCDOGA,                                                                 
  B.GGCDPAT1,                                                                
  CASE WHEN B.GGNOUGRAT <> ' ' THEN B.GGNOUGRAT ELSE B.GGNOUG END AS NOUG,   
  90,                                                                        
  SUM(A.TXMTLOYANX)                                                          
FROM                                                                         
  IKOS_F.UGCSALP A,                                                          
  IKOS_F.UGP B                                                               
WHERE                                                                        
  TXDTDBVL >= YEAR(MAX(CURRENT DATE,B.GGDTMSUG)) * 10000 + MONTH(MAX(CURRENT DATE,B.GGDTMSUG)) * 100 + 01 AND
  TXDTDBVL <= YEAR(MAX(CURRENT DATE,B.GGDTMSUG)) * 10000 + MONTH(MAX(CURRENT DATE,B.GGDTMSUG)) * 100 + 31    
  AND (                                                                      
    (B.GGCDOGA, B.GGNOUG) IN (                                               
      SELECT                                                                 
        DISTINCT IWCDORG,                                                      
        IWCDLOGT                                                               
      FROM                                                                     
        IKOS_F.IMWXRUP                                                         
    )                                                                          
    OR (B.GGCDOGA, B.GGNOUGRAT) IN (                                           
      SELECT                                                                   
        DISTINCT IWCDORG,                                                      
        IWCDLOGT                                                               
      FROM                                                                     
        IKOS_F.IMWXRUP                                                         
    )                                                                          
  )                                                                            
  AND A.TXCDOGA = B.GGCDOGA                                                    
  AND A.TXNOUG = B.GGNOUG                                                      
  AND A.TXCDTTARIF = B.GGCDTTARIF                                              
GROUP BY                                                                       
  B.GGCDOGA,                                                                   
  B.GGCDPAT1,            
CASE WHEN B.GGNOUGRAT <> ' ' THEN B.GGNOUGRAT ELSE B.GGNOUG END; 

I tried HAVING with
SELECT MAX(TXDTDBVL) FROM (VALUES (CURRENT DATE),(B.GGDTMSUG))

but I got lost...

What DB2 platform are you using? z/OS, iSeries, LUW...

MAX() works over multiple rows. You probably want to use GREATEST() to compute in the same row.

It's typically trivial to manage and compare dates when using the proper DATE data type. If you are simulating dates with NUMERIC values it gets trickier. You can use CTEs to preprocess dates and bring everything to the numeric domain.
For example, you can do:
with
p (cd) as (
  select 
    year(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + month(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + day(CURRENT DATE) 
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select *
from t, p
where txdtdbvl between
  trunc(greatest(p.cd, t.ggdtmsug) / 100) * 100 + 01 and
  trunc(greatest(p.cd, t.ggdtmsug) / 100) * 100 + 31;

In this example the first and third rows are selected as expected. The second one does not meet the condition.
See running example at db<>fiddle.
